# Unity3D - Any way to keep the quality of texture/object no matter the selected graphics settings?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently making a game where there are a lot of paintings on walls and you have to get clues from the paintings, the problem is while lowering the graphics quality the paintings are really blurry and low quality making them pretty much useless for the point of the game.

Is there any way to always keep max quality for the paintings no matter if a user picks low graphics?

Answer (score 0):

You can influence [Quality Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html) in unity where you can manage level of graphical render. You can edit these levels (specific settings what influece your paintings the most) or remove them. IMO there is no option to exclude one gameobject/tag from this settings.

Than for optimalizing your game you can use [LOD groups](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LODGroup.html#LODGroup) where you can set lower level of detail with greater distance and [Occlusion Culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html#:%7E:text=Occlusion%20Culling%20is%20a%20feature,(occluded)%20by%20other%20objects.&text=Occlusion%20culling%20removes%20additional%20objects,entirely%20obscured%20by%20nearer%20objects.) as compensation.